# Equivalent to PHP's include in C#

Tags: c#, php

What is the equivalent command to PHP's include() in C# ?

For example, PHP's include is used as so : include("ex.php");

Can I do the same in C#?

Comment: Do you whant the "include" to be in the .aspx file? or in the .cs file? You could use normal javascript include, since there is no true c# way to do this since c# is OO-programing.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean in ASP.Net using C# you can create a user control (.ascx)  and add it in your .aspx page.
If you are doing MVC you can create a partial view.

The closest thing I can think of would be after creating an ascx user control named "MyUserControl"

in your page_load or pre_render :

```
MyUserControl cont = new MyUserControl();
this.Controls.Add(cont);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing in C#. It's not a scripting language, so including a block of script wouldn't make sense.

What are you trying to accomplish? There are ways to do similar things in C#.

Comment: Why does the fact it's compiled make the concept of an include nonsensical? It would be some sort of compiler directive, but there's no reason it couldn't be done. (although that doesn't change the fact that c# doesn't have such a concept)

Comment: @Andrew: because most compiled languages have learned from the mistakes of C and C++ and have abandoned include files.

Comment: Depending on what you need it for.  I stumbled across this question because I just want to include some html across multiple pages. Easier than creating an ashx (or w/e).. `Response.WriteFile()` accomplishes what I would have used PHP's `include()` for..

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct equivalent.  You use [references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yabyz3h4.aspx) to "link" with other CLR assemblies (access their type information), and the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28VS.80%29.aspx) directive to import namespaces.

For example, the [`FontCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.fontcollection.aspx) class is in the `System.Drawing.dll` assembly, and the `System.Drawing.Text` namespace.  So you would add `System.Drawing` as a reference, and add the line:

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if this is what you want to do. But just for the case, maybe you have a look at:

```
<%         
    Response.WriteFile( "YourFile.whatever" )
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answers mentioning the `using` Directive and adding references to assemblies to your project (or at command line when compiling) there is a way to load other compiled .NET assemblies at runtime.

[`Assembly.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) will load an assembly (compiled c# file/.dll) into memory, allowing you to find and use types within that assembly. This can be used when building a plugin architecture. You publish an assembly with an interface for a plugin contract. Plugin makers can link to that that assembly and implement your interface. Your application can then load plugin assemblies, check for any types implementing your plugin interface and load and use those types into your application.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing comparable in C# is `using`, which imports namespaces defined in assemblies referenced from the project.  You **cannot** "include" a file in the sense that you dump the content right into your code.

For example, if your project references the System.Xml assembly, then the following code would allow you to access all of the classes in that namespace without fully qualifying their names:

```
using System.Xml;
```

This will let you use the type `System.Xml.XmlDocument`, for example, by specifying it as `XmlDocument` instead of its full type name `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

The `using` keyword is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in C#.

You're going to want to create an instance of a C# class and use that to invoke methods/attributes from other 'packages' (C# classes).

You can also use a `using` direction to be able to references assemblies from other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Using is vaguely similar. It references another class that can then be used from that file, but it doesn't include the contents of that file directly inline.

```
using system;
```

(right at the beginning of a file)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for c#
@RenderPage("header.cshtml")

This is taken from here:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showfile_c.asp?filename=try_webpages_cs_002

Although I know this post is old, but people stubming to this post can refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what I did ... not sure if this is the right way, but it works...

In the .ascx File, specify a div as container to received the contents of included file.

```
<div id="containerForSomeMarkup" runat="server"></div>
```

In the .ascx.cs file, initialise this in the onInit() method or other methods as required...

```
containerForSomeMarkup.InnerHtml = File.ReadAllText("Full path of file to be included");
```

Coming from PHP world, for me, this approach helps keep the markup organized and intelligble...