# Place methods in another source file, without creating a new class

Tags: c#, xna

In working on a C# XNA project I've created quite a few methods to minimize code in the default LoadContent/Update/Draw methods. I am wondering if it is possible to move those methods out of the Game1.cs file into another source file without encapsulating them in a new class and passing object references?

I've tried creating a new .CS file with the proper using statements and namespace declaration, but the compiler tells me that it is missing a class declaration so I don't believe I am doing it right. Currently I've created a HelperMethod class that I instantiate at the top of the Game1.cs file, but it would be nice to be able to use something like an include_once from PHP in C#.

Is there a way to create a method or function file and include it in my code, or should I stick with the HelperMethod class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

All methods in C# must be inside an object.

You're thinking about it all wrong if you're worried about passing references around. References are light weight.. and you've just smacked head first into Premature Optimization.

Comment: Premature optimization?  It sounds like he's simply trying to keep the size of the file down.  That does nothing about run speed, it's for the humans.

Comment: "without encapsulating them in a new class and passing object references". OP sounds worried about passing references around.. that is what I was referring to.

Comment: I'm choosing your answer as the correct one because you mention Premature Optimization; a term I had not heard of. Definitely describes what I am going through right now, and will be useful in future projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use partial classes to break a class definition across multiple files.  See this article on MSDN for more information: Partial Classes and Methods (C# Programming Guide) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After reading this:

[Equivalent to PHP's include in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188550/equivalent-to-phps-include-in-c-sharp)

it would appear that the best course of action is to stay with the helper class that I have currently in place. It doesn't appear that compiled languages make use of any sort of include function that would just append code to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

+1 on STLDeveloper's suggestion on using Partial Classes and Methods.

Additional idea: if it makes sense for what you're trying to accomplish (especially if your code may be reusable in other XNA Game projects you might have), create your own Game class that extends Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game and have Game1 inherit from that.  That would include the methods you've written in a separate .cs file but keep your Game1.cs "smaller".

Game.cs:

```
public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    /* Your methods here */
}
```

Game1.cs:

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    /* More of your methods here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for extension methods?

[Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Or you can try keeping a class that houses delegates.

[Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)